# How to solve InnerText error 'Cannot get inner content of because the contents are not literal'

Tags: c#, asp.net

In my project there is a print button . after clicking that button I want to open a popup but it's not loading

```
    <table class="inputForm">
        <tfoot>
          <tr>
             <td align="right">
              <asp:Button ID="btnPrint" OnClick="btnPrint_Click" Text="Printuiuiuiui" CssClass="button" runat="server" Visible="true" />
             </td>
          </tr>
         </tfoot>
        </table> 

    Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "s1", "<script FOR=window EVENT=onload>openViewer('" + (int)ABCDEF.enReportName.PortfolioPrint + "');</script>");
```

Now when I debugged Page.ClientScript throws error in Header

```
Header = {InnerText = {"Cannot get inner content of ctl00 because the contents are not literal."}}
```

openViewer is a function that shows popup

```
function openViewer(reportName) {

  sPath = "/ADDCD/Popups/ifggfjfj.aspx?Viewer.aspx?ReportName=" + reportName;
   
  if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Chrome") != -1) {

    return window.open(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");
  }
  else if (navigator.userAgent.indexOf("Firefox") != -1) {

    return window.open(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");
  }
  else if ((navigator.userAgent.indexOf("MSIE") != -1) || (!!document.documentMode == true)) { //IF IE > 10
           
    return window.showModalDialog(sPath, self, "dialogHeight: 374px; dialogWidth: 430px; status: no; resizable: no; center: yes;");

  }
}
```

**ifggfjfj.aspx**

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Page.master" AutoEventWireup="true" Inherits="Popups_i" CodeBehind="ifggfjfj.aspx.cs" %>

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">
    
    <asp:Literal id="lDoctype" runat="server"><!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd"></asp:Literal>

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head >
        <title>ABCDEF</title>
        <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="/apps/xyzdfg/Script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div style="position:absolute;width:100%;height:100%;overflow:hidden;">
            <iframe frameborder="0" src="<% Response.Write(Server.UrlDecode(Request.QueryString.ToString())); %>" style="width: 100%; height: 100%; ">
            </iframe>
        </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    
</asp:Content>
```

**Viewer.aspx**

```
<%@ Register Assembly="XSAWERTYU" TagPrefix="dica" Namespace="ashgsb.fjgdjgj.kfhgkhg.xcvbmvbmx" %>    

<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="ContentPlaceHolder1" runat="server">

    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head runat="server">
        <title>Report</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../shfhf/dfdfdfdf/css/default.css"/>
        
        <script type="text/javascript">
    
            function Init()
            {
                theForm.document.all.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_viewer.style.width = "100%";
                theForm.document.all.ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_viewer.style.height = "100%";                                                                                            
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>Report content is written in this area </body>
    </html>
    </asp:Content>
```

Now I closed  tag in ifggfjfj.aspx but it's not working. So what am I doing wrong? Anybody can tell me? I don't understand this error at all. Please help

**EDIT:**
Now I get an error like error CS0103: The name or method openViewer does not exist in the current context in this line

```
 Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(typeof(Page), "s1", "<script FOR=window EVENT=onload>openViewer('" + (int)ABCDEF.enReportName.PortfolioPrint + "');</script>");
```

Comment: Are you using webforms for a specific reason? They are VERY old and not even supported in .net core anymore.

Comment: `Page.ClientScript...` is in code-behind I hope? Looks like it's in the HTML.

Comment: @wazz yes it's code behind

Comment: @wazz any clue to slove this issue

Comment: Seems to be related to the `init` function in Viewer.aspx. What happens if you comment that out? It looks like it's just for sizing, so it shouldn't matter if it's there for now.

Comment: @wazz I edited this question. Please take a look into the error